# Remove column from HtmlElement from WebBrowser

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

On my web browser I have a table called table2.

The table contains many rows. This an example of one:

```html
<tr>
    <TH class=ms-rteTableHeaderFirstCol-default>​</TH>
    <TH class=ms-rteTableHeaderOddCol-default>LAN IP​</TH>
    <TH class=ms-rteTableHeaderEvenCol-default>Username​</TH>
    <TH class=ms-rteTableHeaderOddCol-default>Password​</TH>
    <TH class=ms-rteTableHeaderEvenCol-default>Port​</TH>
    <TH class=ms-rteTableHeaderOddCol-default>OS​</TH>
    <TH class=ms-rteTableHeaderEvenCol-default>Extra Info​</TH>
    <TD class="ms-rteTableOddCol-default" Name="tdVPN"><BUTTON>Ping</BUTTON></TD>
</tr>
```

I need to remove the last column with the name `tdVPN`. I am able to get the correct cell with this code:

```
HtmlElement table2 = webbSPPagina.Document.GetElementById("table2");
HtmlElementCollection trCollection = table2.GetElementsByTagName("tr");

foreach (HtmlElement tr in trCollection)
{
            foreach (HtmlElement td in tr.Children)
            {
                if (td.Name.Equals("tdVPN"))
                {
                    td.OuterHtml = "";
                }
            }
}
```

But when I try to change the `OuterHtml` I get an exception:

> Property is not supported on this type of HtmlElement

Comment: removing the column on client-side with javascript is not an option?

Comment: I have never used javascript before but I don't think it is an option. The column is added by myself and not part of the real site.

Comment: I still think a javascript solution is the neater and the correct one. Every HTML request via a browser allows manipulation in javascript. Once a request response is sent to a browser, the response's contents can be manipulated via javascript. This is what is called client side processing.

Answer (score 0):

what if you try the following

```
        if (td.Name.Equals("tdVPN"))
        {
            td.Attributes.Add("display", "none");
        }
```